# Set <a>class = "active" using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a nav bar that I've made common throughout pages so it's easier to update, however now my `class="active"` on the `<a>`tags is of course not working.  I've been trying to fiddle around with this using Javascript, so that when these are clicked, the active state adds to that link and is removed from the previous.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //active state  
  $(function() {
    $('.start').addClass('active');
    $('#Side_Menu a').click(function() {
      $('#Side_Menu a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="Side_Menu">
  <li><a href="dashboard.php" class="active"><i class="fa fa-th" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Dashboard</a></li>
  <li><a href="blog_posts.php"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Blog Posts</a></li>
  <li><a href="addnewpost.php"><i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Add New Post</a></li>
  <li><a href="categories.php"><i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Categories</a></li>
  <li><a href="admins.php"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Manage Admins</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have the `active` state on the first `<a>` because this is the default load page.  Not sure why this is not working.  It navigates around & I'm not getting any errors, but the JS is not doing it's job.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You must have any mean to validate or check document location and then compare it with the href of the navigation bar's links.

Comment: It is working when I added `.active { color: pink }` or what you want...

Comment: Your code is working with a class `.active {color: green}`

Comment: I was thinking this.  active class is being pulled from bootstrap.  Just the standard blue.  If this is being added or removed in JS, why wouldn't it just pickup the BS style?

Comment: .action ?  I don't understand that.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Big typo sorry.

Comment: you mean a .active class.  I'm going to try this.  I don't understand this .action...?

Comment: My goodness, forget that action word! `(:`

Comment: I added a style on page .active with the bg blue.  It turns blue alright, but only on the dashboard link <a>

Comment: **[Your code works](https://jsfiddle.net/1ru0o02h/2/)**, provided you have an `.active` class. Voting to close as the issue cannot be reproduced

Comment: Enough, please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I did this @Sphinx using blue, it works but only on the dashboard link.  Once I navigate to another page, it restarts the code, so the active link is again the default dashboard <a>

Comment: If you are using bootstrap, please add your bootstrap cdn link, then add bootstrap as one tag for your question.

Comment: Thanks @sphinx, it's in there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
            $('.start').addClass('active');
            $('#Side_Menu a').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#Side_Menu a').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
        });
    });
```

I prevented the default, just for testing purposes. If the page is unloaded (you navigate to another page) you probably wont notice the changes on th HTML.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.start').addClass('active');
 $('#Side_Menu a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#Side_Menu a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
 });
});
```

```css
a.active {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="Side_Menu">
 <li><a href="dashboard.php" class="active"><i class="fa fa-th" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Dashboard</a></li>
 <li><a href="blog_posts.php"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Blog Posts</a></li>
 <li><a href="addnewpost.php"><i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Add New Post</a></li>
 <li><a href="categories.php"><i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Categories</a></li>
 <li><a href="admins.php"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Manage Admins</a></li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT:** This code will select the current link in a very simple way using jQuery and parsing `location.href`:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var url      = String(location.href),
            selected = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        $('#Side_Menu a[href="' + selected + '"]').addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why should they try that?

Comment: The only difference here is a little more of bytes traveling from a server to the client.

Comment: Just to make sure the class is removed from all the a elements but not for the clicked element.

Comment: @Ele Check the snippet for a working example using the code i posted a while ago.

Comment: But when it actually redirects to another page, it re-runs the code and starts back at dashboard.

Comment: @EP19 of course this solution won't work with no server side code, i will improve it. Check back soon.

Comment: yes, I'm working local right now in Xammp, so the links are active.

Comment: @EP19 this las commit will use jQuery to set the active button. You should use PHP to achieve this.

Comment: thanks @muecas.  already on it...& it solves the problem.  I'll scrap my code and use this, it's time to move on :)

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to a different page, the whole thing starts again. Your JS works when you click the link, but then straight away you navigate to the other page and everything starts from scratch.

Just for fun, if you take away all the `href` attributes from the menu, your JS will work, but you won't navigate anywhere.

It's simplest to add the `active` class in your PHP templates instead of using JS. For example:

```
class="<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'dashboard.php' ? 'active' : '' ?>"...
```

Comment: This is may be a comment, it is not relevant to the question. The OP talks about client-side issue.

Comment: Can you illustrate further this example - or point me to a similar link.  I understand what you're saying w/ regards to the JS, but unsure of how to implement the php fix.

Comment: ohhh, you mean place class="<?php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']"... within the <a> tag itself.  And do this for each link?

Comment: Yeah that's right, with the 'dashboard.php' changed to match the `href` of each one. I'm not great at PHP, this isn't a very smart way to do it, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of that.  I could do a variable check based on URI and set the class based on results.  It's not JS, but I just want it to work!

Answer (score -3):

You are repeating the same code (document ready):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //active state  
    $(function() {
        $('.start').addClass('active');
        $('#Side_Menu a').click(function() {
        $('#Side_Menu a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');             
        });
    });
});
```

You should and try to use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //active state  
        $('.start').addClass('active');
        $('#Side_Menu li a').click(function() {
        $('#Side_Menu li a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active'); 
        });            
});
```

And what's the "start" class for?

Comment: Actually `$(function() {})` is the preferred signature as per docs

Comment: I've modified using your code, no errors, but I'm not seeing active on my nav links,

Comment: This is an issue, but not one that is causing the problem.

Comment: It's not even an issue. It's redundant, but harmless.